# Local Environment Stripping Port Number...help tracking down the redirect?

Tags: redirect

I am trying to set up my site on a local environment using MAMP. When I install my theme onto the local environment, the theme seems to try and redirect the site away from the URL with the port number:

http://localhost:8888/csdev
redirects to
http://localhost/csdev

Any thoughts on how I can track down the code doing the redirection?

Comment: Hi Mark, check my answer below! With every WordPress instal, you should check if the URL's are configured correctly, even on a local WP test website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) are configured correctly. Go to > Settings > General / see image below:

[image: WordPress settings]

Enter your URL with the port number: http://localhost:8888/csdev 
This will solve WordPress unnecessary redirecting you.